# Convert a simple hashtable to HTML

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write an html page that holds process names currently running.
 
I've tried this:

```
 $htmlFile="c:\HTMLFILE.HTML"

 $HashTBL=@{label="PROCESS NAMES";Expression={$_.name}}

 $HtmData=Get-Process |select -Verbose $HashTBL
 $HtmData | ConvertTo-Html -Title "Running processes" |Out-File $htmlFile
```

But I got this page:
as you can see the column name is missing and showing as wild card,

```
*

AcroRd32 
AcroRd32 
ApMsgFwd 
ApntEx 
Apoint 
armsvc 
audiodg 
CCleaner64 
chrome 
chrome 
chrome 
chrome 
chrome 
chrome 
chrome 
chrome 
chrome 
chrome
```

If I select multiple properties that works fine:

```
 $htmlFile="c:\HTMLFILE.HTML"

 $HashTBL=@{label="PROCESS NAMES";Expression={$_.name}}   

 $HtmData=Get-Process |select -Verbose $HashTBL,id
 $HtmData | ConvertTo-Html -Title "Running processes" |Out-File $htmlFile
```

produce a correct columns headers (just added ID property)
but still want to use a single property as hash table

Comment: Looks like a bug in `ConvertTo-Html`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the properties to convertTo-html like this:

```
$htmlFile="c:\HTMLFILE.HTML"
$HashTBL=@{label="PROCESS NAMES";Expression={$_.name}}
$HtmData=Get-Process |select -Verbose $HashTBL
$HtmData | ConvertTo-Html -Title "Running processes" -Property 'PROCESS NAMES' |Out-File $htmlFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just format the property within select-object? If all you want to do is retitle the column, you can do that within Select-Object using a hash table.

```
$htmlFile="c:\HTMLFILE.HTML"
get-process | Select-Object @{n='PROCESS NAMES';e={$_.Name}} | Convertto-html -Title "Running processes" | Out-File $htmlfile
```